# Vungle ads are not displaying in portrait mode

Tags: android, vungle-ads

I have integrated vungle video ads in my android application successfully but the ads are displaying in landscape mode only, but  i want the ads to be displayed in the portrait mode .

I have done the following implementation in manifest file

```
 <activity
 android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

And also for my activity :

```
<activity
            android:name=".CreateGame"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

And I followed this url to setup the vungle ads 
https://github.com/Vungle/vungle-resources/blob/master/English/Android/current-release/android-dev-guide.md

And in my CreteGame Activity I followed the below code

in onCreate method I have done this thing :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.creategame);
            final String app_id = "App_id";

            // initialize the Publisher SDK
            vunglePub.init(this, app_id);
        }
```

And I followed the below coding in my function()

```
final AdConfig globalAdConfig = vunglePub.getGlobalAdConfig();

             globalAdConfig.setOrientation(Orientation.autoRotate);
             globalAdConfig.setOrientation(Orientation.matchVideo);
            if(!vunglePub.isAdPlayable()) {
                return;
            }
            else{
                vunglePub.playAd(globalAdConfig);

            }
```

Please help me to display the ads in portrait view only 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should remove:

globalAdConfig.setOrientation(Orientation.matchVideo);

and leave only:

globalAdConfig.setOrientation(Orientation.autoRotate);

It will display an ad in portrait if you hold a device in portrait.
"matchVideo" should be mostly show it in landscape mode.

Thanks,